# error Missing JSDoc comment require-jsdoc cloud functions firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, jsdoc

Hi I am getting this lint error 'error  Missing JSDoc comment  require-jsdoc' in my index .js file when doing firebase deploy.  Can anyone help?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.announceProduct = functions.database
    .ref("/products/{productID}")
    .onCreate((event) => {
      const product = event.val();
      sendNotification(product);
      return event.ref.set(product);
    });

function sendNotification(product) {
  const title = product.title;
  const cost = product.cost;

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "New Product Available",
      body: title + " for £ " + cost,
      sound: "default",
    },
  };

  console.log(payload);

  const topic = "newProducts";
  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload);
}
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Check your eslint rules https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/require-jsdoc

Answer (score 0):

Also had this very annoying error before. It occurs because the "sendNotification" function lacks a JSDoc comment. Basically linter wants you to comment on your functions as its helpful for other developers to understand the function's purpose and usage.

Can fix it by adding a comment for the function like this:

```
/**
 * Sends a notification for a new product.
 */
function sendNotification(product) {

...your original code 
}
```